# change data capture in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have got a requirement to do , but I am confused how to do it. 
I have two dataframes. so first time i got the below data file1

file1
prodid, lastupdatedate, indicator

```
00001,,A
00002,01-25-1981,A
00003,01-26-1982,A
00004,12-20-1985,A
```

the output should be

```
0001,1900-01-01, 2400-01-01, A
0002,1981-01-25, 2400-01-01, A
0003,1982-01-26, 2400-01-01, A
0004,1985-12-20, 2400-10-01, A
```

Second time i got another one file2

prodid, lastupdatedate, indicator

```
00002,01-25-2018,U
00004,01-25-2018,U
00006,01-25-2018,A
00008,01-25-2018,A
```

I want the end result like

```
00001,1900-01-01,2400-01-01,A
00002,1981-01-25,2018-01-25,I
00002,2018-01-25,2400-01-01,A
00003,1982-01-26,2400-01-01,A
00004,1985-12-20,2018-01-25,I
00004,2018-01-25,2400-01-01,A
00006,2018-01-25,2400-01-01,A
00008,2018-01-25,2400-01-01,A
```

so whatever the updates are there in the second file that date should come in the second column and the default date (2400-01-01) should come in the third column and the relavant indicator. The default indicator is A

I have started like this

```html
val spark=SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("creating data frame for csv")
    .getOrCreate()
   
    import spark.implicits._ 
    val df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("d:/prod.txt")
  
    val df1 = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("d:/prod1.txt")
  

val newdf = df.na.fill("01-01-1900",Seq("lastupdatedate"))

if((df1("indicator")=='U') && (df1("prodid")== newdf("prodid"))){
    val df3 = df1.except(newdf)
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your help please. Am using spark 2.3

Comment: how did you get `I` in the result dataframe?

Comment: it was my requirement. That i  need to save the result in the database. when the data is updated , then in the result dataframe it should indicate as 'i'

Comment: `00004` is updated but you have `A` and `00005` is not updated then how come you have `I`? thats why I asked whats that `I` for ?

Comment: hi ramesh, i have edited the question. sorry previously i typed incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `join` them with `prodid` and use some `when` function to manipulate the dataframes to the expected output. You should `filter` the updated dataframes for second rows and merge them back (I have included comments for explaining each part of the code)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//filling empty lastupdatedate and changing the date to the expected format
val newdf = df.na.fill("01-01-1900",Seq("lastupdatedate"))
  .withColumn("lastupdatedate", date_format(unix_timestamp(trim(col("lastupdatedate")), "MM-dd-yyyy").cast("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

//changing the date to the expected format of the second dataframe
val newdf1 = df1.withColumn("lastupdatedate", date_format(unix_timestamp(trim(col("lastupdatedate")), "MM-dd-yyyy").cast("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

//joining both dataframes and updating columns according to your needs
val tempdf = newdf.as("table1").join(newdf1.as("table2"),Seq("prodid"), "outer")
    .select(col("prodid"),
      when(col("table1.lastupdatedate").isNotNull, col("table1.lastupdatedate")).otherwise(col("table2.lastupdatedate")).as("lastupdatedate"),
      when(col("table1.indicator").isNotNull, when(col("table2.lastupdatedate").isNotNull, col("table2.lastupdatedate")).otherwise(lit("2400-01-01"))).otherwise(lit("2400-01-01")).as("defaultdate"),
      when(col("table2.indicator").isNull, col("table1.indicator")).otherwise(when(col("table2.indicator") === "U", lit("I")).otherwise(col("table2.indicator"))).as("indicator"))

//filtering tempdf for duplication
val filtereddf = tempdf.filter(col("indicator") === "I")
                        .withColumn("lastupdatedate", col("defaultdate"))
                        .withColumn("defaultdate", lit("2400-01-01"))
                        .withColumn("indicator", lit("A"))

//finally merging both dataframes
tempdf.union(filtereddf).sort("prodid", "lastupdatedate").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|prodid|lastupdatedate|defaultdate|indicator|
+------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|1     |1900-01-01    |2400-01-01 |A        |
|2     |1981-01-25    |2018-01-25 |I        |
|2     |2018-01-25    |2400-01-01 |A        |
|3     |1982-01-26    |2400-01-01 |A        |
|4     |1985-12-20    |2018-01-25 |I        |
|4     |2018-01-25    |2400-01-01 |A        |
|6     |2018-01-25    |2400-01-01 |A        |
|8     |2018-01-25    |2400-01-01 |A        |
+------+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh for the reply. It was as expected.

Comment: I think I have done it now. Since am new to stackoverflow, may be I missed it previously. . Now had I done it ?

Comment: In the above mentioned way I will be getting the file each day, and the output data will be appended. So in such case do I need to write shell-script?

Comment: its your choice to write a script or do other things like use streaming or something else

Comment: just click the up button at the place where you accepted :)